# Connecting to access database using code

Tags: c#, ms-access

I am a student How to connect to access database using code ( not using wizard) and retrive values in the textbox in c#
using visual studio 2008.

I have to extract 3 fields from the access database.

Do anybody know.  Pl help.

Answer (score 4):

[OleDbConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbconnection.aspx) is the standard class to query an Access database. [Here's an example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288452%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Start by reading up on ADO.NET and then use the OleDb Data Provider.  Once you have the values it should be trivial to put them into a text box.

Here is a good ADO.NET tutorial:

- http://www.codersource.net/asp-net/ado-net/c-and-ado-net.aspx

And some good OLEDB info:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6d9ew87b%28v=VS.71%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

In addition: Get the "Visual C# 2010 Samples" from

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/cs2010samples/Wiki/View.aspx?title=Home

and look at the

"OLEDB: Demonstrates how to use a Microsoft Access database from C# by creating a dataset and adding tables to it."

sample.

Comment: Sorry about missing that. In an attempt to compensate: I tried (and succeded) in compiling & running the solution using Visual C# 2008 (Express) - after copying the .mdb to bin\debug