# C# Win Form that opens and Edits an Access Database

Tags: c#, ms-access

I am trying to learn to use C# with Microsoft Access files.

I want to Create a C# win Form App that opens a .mdb file, view the table and edits it
and saves it again.

I have been searching for examples for two days now and the only examples I find is apps that was written in 2001 -2003.

Can anyone please direct me to a good example or tutorial?

I use Visual Studio 2010

I will appreciate it a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here a great example : [Access Database Editor in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1909/Access-Database-Editor-in-C)

And you can refer to [Connecting to access database using code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4995333/connecting-to-access-database-using-code) here on stackoverflow.com there is many examples there